# What does renderSortByOptions() do?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, jsx

I'm studying React and i found a great project i'm replicating and trying to understand. So far i had no issues with anything except with the `renderSortByOptions()`. What exactly is happening there? I can see that the `Object.key` is used on the `sortByOptions`-object to get the keys (which are `Best Match, Highest Rated and Most Reviewed` or is it  `best_match` etc.?) but i'm confused why there is a `.map`.

`.map` gets a callback-function where a variable (let) gets declared and in it is the `sortByOptions`-object with  `sortByOption` as an index?! I am really confused about this. kindly explain lines 12 - 18 (basically the `renderSortByOptions()`) for me.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

const sortByOptions = {
  'Best Match': 'best_match',
  'Highest Rated': 'rating',
  'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
};

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  renderSortByOptions() {
    return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
      let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      return <li key={sortByOptionValue}>{sortByOption}</li>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
          <ul>
            {this.renderSortByOptions()}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-fields">
          <input placeholder="Search Businesses" />
          <input placeholder="Where?" />
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-submit">
          <a>Let's Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(obj)` gives you an array of keys in `obj`.

So in your case `sortByOptions` is an object with keys `Best Match`, `Highest Rated` and `Most Reviewed`.

```
const sortByOptions = {
  'Best Match': 'best_match',
  'Highest Rated': 'rating',
  'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
};
```

`Object.keys(sortByOptions)` will return an array `['Best Match', 'Highest Rated', 'Most Reviewed']`.

So this

```
Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(...)
```

is actually

```
['Best Match', 'Highest Rated', 'Most Reviewed'].map(...)
```

`.map` loops over an array returning a new array.

```
Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
  // sortByOption will be each key in the object
  // sortByOptionValue will be the value assigned to that key
  let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
    // you return an <li> element with key and value
    return <li key={sortByOptionValue}>{sortByOption}</li>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function is used to iterate an array passing the array items one by one to the callback function, and return values returned in the callback function. As you can see here the rule with React is that each child produced in that iteration needs to have a unique `key`.

Now the array that the `map` function is iterating (looping through) is the result (or return value) of `Object.keys` which returns an array of the keys in the nominated object. In your case the return value of `Object.keys(sortByOptions)` will be

```
[
  'Best Match',
  'Highest Rated',
  'Most Reviewed'
]
```

So iterating (looping) that array is what your function `renderSortByOptions` is doing.

The variable created inside the callback function is basially the value of the key in the `sortByOptions` object. So for the first item in the iteration the value `sortByOptions[sortByOption]` is `best_match`, the second is `rating` and the third would be `review_count`;

Basically the result of that functiontion will be

```
<li key="best_match">Best Match</li>
<li key="rating">Highest Rated</li>
<li key="review_count">Most Reviewed</li>
```

of course they need to be children of a `<ul>` which is taken care of inside the render function

```
<ul>
    {this.renderSortByOptions()}
</ul>
```

Hope that clarifies things a little :)